# Archive of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is there an archive of the Google maps?

I have noticed that they've updated my city several times over the years that it's been available. I'd be interested in a time-lapse style gif of my house, my neighbourhood, my city, etc...

The best app would include ability to see a region "age" on a delay, but selecting different years would be ok as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the new version of Maps. (See [the official announcement](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/04/go-back-in-time-with-street-view.html).)

1. Go to *Street View*;
2. Click on the clock-like icon in the upper-left corner, just below the address;
3. Navigate to a previous date.

Now:

[image]

Before:

[image]

P.S.: Note that the number of previous views varies from place to place, in some cases just the current one being available.

Answer (score 2):

You can see old imagery in Google Earth. Just use the show [historical imagery button.](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=148094)

Comment: Ok, but that's not work for google maps. The archive of old street views are not on-line. Right?